# What is the basic difference between google sso and google+ sso?

Tags: google-plus, google-sso

What is the basic difference and feature difference between Gmail's account SSO (single Sign On) and SSO using Google plus's account?

What is the basic steps to integrate PHP based Google Plus SSO ?

Comment: Good question but way to broad.  Try reading  SAML or SSO http://www.mutuallyhuman.com/blog/2013/05/09/choosing-an-sso-strategy-saml-vs-oauth2/  I am not even sure you can use SSO with Google anymore I think they have moved everything over to Oauth2.